# What is the right way to provision nodes with static content in Amazon EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an application that loads a .conf file and some additional files on startup. Now I want to run this app in Amazon EKS. What is the best way to inject these files into a pod in Kubernetes? I tried copying them into a directory on the node and mounting that directory in the pod via hostpath. That works but doesn't feel the right way to do it. Does EKS have any autoprovision tool for this?

Comment: You can create a configmap of all the files and mount them into your pod. Let me know if this is the solution you wanted.

Comment: Yes, but I need to put these files into some directory on a node first. And how do I do that in a managed node group?

Comment: You don't need to load them in a directory. All you need is to create configmap/configmaps from any place once you have access to those files and they will be available to all the pods in your namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a fixed config file for your app, you can even burn it inside **docker image**, i.e. copy file in your Dockerfile

If it needs to be configurable during deployment (e.g. it's environment-specific), then indeed, as mentioned by @anmolagrawal above, **ConfigMap** is the right way:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

If you can modify your app to rely on **env vars** or **command-line arguments**, it will make your life a lot simpler, you can just pass those values in the Pod spec, no need for ConfigMap.

But you definitely shouldn't be managing yourself any app-specific content on the Kubernetes nodes.